# Android - How to stop form from saving null to my database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So the form I have written has two fields, a body and a title. I am hoping to get the form to throw a toast message if those fields contain no data to prevent the user from saving it to the database. The code should do one of three things. The first being what I am trying to accomplish above. The second is if the ID intent is null, it will create a new entry, and if the ID intent has content, it will update the database entry with the new content. The problem I am having is when the form fields are null, it still saves. It seems to completely skip over my first IF statement and I cant seem to figure out why. I've tried using both null and "" for the first IF statement, both separately and together. Help?

```
  submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String titleInsert = titleEdit.getText().toString();
                String bodyInsert = bodyEdit.getText().toString();
                String dateTimeValue = dateTimeTextView.getText().toString();
                if ((titleInsert == null || titleInsert == "") || (bodyInsert == null || bodyInsert == "")){
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Please make sure the Title and Body are both filled before saving";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }else if(intentRowId == null){
                    try{
                    mDb.open();
                    mDb.createNote(Integer.parseInt(mIntentId), titleInsert, bodyInsert, dateTimeValue);
                    finish();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    try{
                        mDb.open();
                        mDb.updateNote(longRowId, titleInsert, bodyInsert);
                        finish();
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "SQL Exception Thrown: " + e;
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
                }
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure titleInsert is in fact null when entering the first if statement? I was struggling with the same, but my error was a typecast error in the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `titleInsert.equals("")` etc.

Additionally, you might want to call `titleInsert = titleInsert.trim();` if it is not null, in order to catch blank strings like `" "`.

Edit: if you can use Apache commons lang, you could use the class `StringUtils` which has a `isBlank()` method, which returns true if the string is null, empty or only contains whitespace.

Edit2:

Short explanation on `titleInsert.equals("")`: `==` normally checks for the very same object, not for the equality datawise. Thus `titleInsert` and `""` are not necessarily the same object but might be equal (an empty string). Note that you should use `equals` in almost every case when dealing with (non-null) objects, unless you specifically know you want `==` instead (which is rare, except for checking `obj == null`).

Short example: `new Long(1) == 1L` is likely to yield false, since `new Long(1)` creates an object different to the Long object which is used for the literal `1L` (also note that I did exclude auto(un)boxing by using 1**L**). On the other hand, `new Long(1).equals(1L)` will yield true.

Comment: Using .equals worked like a charm. I tried .isBlank() but my app didnt seem to recognize it as a method. Not sure if its just not built into Android or I was doing something wrong. Still new to all this so thank you very much!

Comment: As I said,  `isBlank()` is a method of the class `StringUtils` which is part of the Apache Commons Lang library. You'd need to add that library in order to use that method.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 titleInsert.equals("")
```

or

```
 "".equals(titleInsert)
```

instead of

```
 titleInsert == ""
```